# Managed DLL Method failing in installshield

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, installshield, managed

Ok, so I have the following class library, which I wrote in C#:

```
public class Program
{
    public void GetProductID(string location, out string productId)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
        var item = new Win32Product();
        //var crap = (collection as IEnumerable<ManagementObject>).Where(o => o["InstallLocation"].ToString().StartsWith(location));
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
        {
            try
            {
                item = new Win32Product();
                item.IdentifyingNumber = (string)obj["IdentifyingNumber"];
                item.InstallLocation = (string)obj["InstallLocation"];
                item.Name = (string)obj["Name"];
            }
            catch
            { }  //shut up. I know it's an empty catch block. Its fine.
                 //If there are exceptions thrown, I don't want the data, I just
                 //want to keep running.
        }
        productId = item.ProductID.ToString();
    }        
} 

public class Win32Product
{
   //properties
}
```

Not a lot to it, `GetProductId()` just searches for any installed programs below a given directory. It works fine if I test it elsewhere, but when running from installshield (as a control event), it fails (return value 3).

Kind of a vague question, I guess, but any idea why `GetProductInfo()` would be failing coming from installshield?

Comment: What do you mean "test it elsewhere"? And what's return code 3? Is the .NET framework loaded when running InstallShield?

Comment: WMI can be rather complex regarding permissions etc. - perhaps installshield is running it in a "restricted context"...

Comment: @xxbbcc "Test it elsewhere" means writing another application which imports the dll and uses that method. Doing that worked fine. Return code 3 is (as far as I can find) just a general error, saying that the Action failed.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt can you verify that the .NET Framework is, in fact, loaded for your dll?

Comment: @Yahia what might I do to fix it if that were the case? And keep in mind that the first time I ever used installshield was last week.

Comment: @xxbbcc I would have thought installshield would have taken care of that one, as the option is called "managed code". How would you recommend I check?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I'm not familiar with InstallShield (we use InnoSetup) - I'm trying to guess your problem. :) Another thing to try (based on some forums) is to add `[ComVisible(true)]` to your assembly. Here's a forum link I found: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=176526

Answer (score 2):

Here's some reading material for you:

[Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) Managed Custom Actions](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html)

[Reasons DTF is Better](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/07/reasons-dtf-is-better.html)

BTW, the Win32_Product class is a POS. It does a very poor job of wrapping the underlying MSI API.  When you switch to DTF, use the ProductInstallation::GetProducts method instead.  It does a much better job of calling MsiEnumProductsEx.

Comment: I'd like to look into this today, but I'm getting a 404 on the link to the download, from your blog (which I was impressed by, by the way). I also couldn't find it by rummaging through WiX's sourceforge. Anywhere else I can find this download?